# Force sound over 3.5mm jack and video over HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi

I am building an application where the sound needs to be over the 3.5mm jack and video over HDMI.

However, sometimes it does send the sound over HDMI and 3.5mm jack. And sometimes it just uses HDMI only.

How can I force the sound always goes over 3.5mm jack (I do not care if the sound gets duplicated over HDMI, I will turn of the TV sound)?

Thankyou,
Rick

Comment: Have [a look here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi-mode-options) at `hdmi_drive` and `hdmi_group` settings for `/boot/config.txt`.   I haven't tested or looked into this, but at a guess, using DMT may exclude the sound from HDMI (and `hdmi_drive=1` definitely will), which may mean it goes out via the headphone jack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use rasp-config to force sound in 3.5 jack. To do so use below commannd

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and then select

```
9 Advanced Options             Configure advanced settings
```

and then select

```
A9 Audio        Force audio out through HDMI or 3.5mm jack
```

and finally

```
1 Force 3.5mm ('headphone') jack
```

Comment: in the more recent versions (bullseye, 2023) the option is now under `1 System Options` -> `S2 Audio`.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking to achieve the same result from the command line, here is the extract from the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md):

> COMMAND LINE
>
> The following command, entered in the command line, will switch the
>   audio output to HDMI:
>
> `amixer cset numid=3 2`
>
> Here the output is being set to 2, which is
>   HDMI. Setting the output to 1 switches to analogue (headphone jack).
>   The default setting is 0 which is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

For Raspberry Pi 4, an update to [@rajesh6115's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/53531/rajesh6115) answer:

use rasp-config to force sound in 3.5 jack. To do so use below commannd

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and then select

```
1 System Options       Configure system settings
```

and then select

```
S2 Audio             Select audio out through HDMI or 3.5mm jack
```

and finally

```
1 Headphones
```