# No sound through 3.5mm jack

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, audio, audio-playback

I've followed the instructions to "[force sound over 3.5mm jack](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61304)" but when I run `omxplayer example.mp3` I get no audio. When I force omxplayer to play over the 3.5mm jack using `omxplayer -o local example.mp3` it works. How do I change the system-wide default to 3.5mm so when I run `omxplayer example.mp3` (or play audio through another app) it works?

Comment: set up an alias  `alias omxplayer="omxplayer -o local "`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not actually interested in omxplayer. I'm just using that to debug. I want audio to work in other apps.

Comment: `not actually interested in omxplayer` ...your post implies otherwise

Answer (score 4):

The [Raspberry Pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md) covers three ways to force audio. Try the first two methods:

1. **Desktop volume control**
   Right-clicking the volume icon on the desktop taskbar brings up the audio output selector;
2. **Command line**
   This command will switch the audio output to HDMI:

   ```
   amixer cset numid=3 2
   ```

   > Here the output is being set to 2, which is HDMI. Setting the output to 1 switches to analogue (headphone jack). The default setting is 0 which is automatic.
3. **raspi-config**
   Go to `Advanced` -> `Audio`, HDMI and analogue should appear here